# git-lfs checkout older version of binary file

Tags: git-lfs

**EDIT**:
So apparently, I asked this about `git` when I wanted `git-lfs`, which apperently behaves differently.   In git you can do:

```
git show tag-name:foo.bin > foo-tag-name.bin
```

to get an older version of a file.   In `git-lfs`, if you do this, you get:

```
~> git show HEAD^:foo.a > foo.orig.a
~> more foo.orig.a
version https://git-lfs.github.com/spec/v1
oid sha256:a2da7b663ad2aef3316adc804f2ea23a17ab64d61638de16d9d7e097fdaacd49
size 44634
```

So, how would I get an older version of a binary file in `git-lfs` without overwriting the original?

Comment: The problem here is that you're not using Git. You're using Git-LFS, which is a wrapper *around* Git, that sometimes stores files "off site". When it does so, it stores *in* Git a pointer to the off-site storage location of the file. If you ask Git "what's in this file" Git gets you the pointer to the off-site storage, which is what you see here. How you have *Git-LFS* retrieve the file, well, that'a a question for [tag:git-lfs], not for [tag:git].

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of that.   I'll modify the question.